# CSS - How to center a div relative to a background image positioned as cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center a div relative to another div which has a background image positioned as cover.

html:

```
<div id="back">
  <div id="box">
    <p>test 1</p>
    <p>test 2</p>
    <p>test 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#back{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/White_square_in_purple_background.svg/450px-White_square_in_purple_background.svg.png');
  background-repat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box{
  position: absolute;
  top:10%;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 20%;
  background: red;
}
```

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8x7tgrqm/

I'm trying to center the red div always inside the white box in background at different screen sizes. Try to resize the window to see what I mean.
I was wondering if there is a way in CSS or even JS to have the box always centered into the background white box.

thanks

Comment: Do you want the red to completely cover the white?

Comment: yes or anyway fill as much as possible the white box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the awesome vmax unit:

http://jsfiddle.net/x5m3w40o/2/

```
#box{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:57vmax;
    height:57vmax;
    background: red;
}
```

You probably need to adjust the 57 vmax value to something like 58-59 to make it completely cover the white rectangle in this particular case.

Comment: way better than the solution I was about to post

Comment: wonderful thanks. I'm using it with a rectangle and I have some issues because it's not pixel perfect as in the jsfiddle but I can live with that thanks!!!